# Как понять когда меня разбанят на stackoverflow

Tags: обсуждение

На сайте написано, что разбанят после того, когда у меня отрицательные баллы превысят положительные баллы, так где эти отрицательные баллы посмотреть?
И ещё вопрос, могут ли меня разбанить, не за счёт того что я исправлю свои старые вопросы, а за счёт новых ответов.